# Google Cloud Messaging exception

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm cloning into my desktop the following repository: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services.git

and then I import the

```
google-services/android/gcm
```

into Android Studio.

Then I follow the instructions and put the API_KEY inside the

```
GcmSender
```

in line 31. When I run the app, I get an exception.

```
java.io.IOException: INVALID_SENDER
        at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zzc(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getToken(Unknown Source)
        at gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.RegistrationIntentService.onHandleIntent(RegistrationIntentService.java:54)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

[image: GCM error screenshot]

The instructions mention that I should copy the google-services.json file I just downloaded into the app or mobile?

I don't know where to find the json file. Maybe this is reason that  I got exception.

Comment: invalid sender means you have to set valid project id in code , please cross check project id .

Comment: In which class though? I only put the API_KEY CODE.

Comment: do you have common utility class

Comment: Please look at this this link. https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm/app/src/main

Comment: There is no utility class.

Comment: in RegistrationIntentService  class what you add at (R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId

Comment: yes. I just fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was easy. I had to insert the senderId inside the string value folder.

```
<string name="gcm_defaultSenderId">3xxxxxxxxxxx</string>
```

Comment: This answer is wrong, you don't need to explicitly add an entry for `gcm_defaultSenderId` in the `strings.xml` file.

From the GCM example comments: *`R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId` (the Sender ID) is typically derived from `google-services.json`*.

That value is derived for you by the `com.google.gms.google-services` gradle plugin.